# If I reset my master password, is it effect with keystore sign?

Tags: android-studio

It might be dumb to ask, but I really have a problem with my master password. I need to generate the apk file, but I totally forgot my master password. The question is can I reset my master password, and if i did, is there any effect with my keystore? Can I use the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `KeyStore`, think of it like if you using the same `KeyStore` in your office and home and you reset the master password at home, how it will affect the `KeyStore` in office?

Well this was a simple example :) Master password is an extra layer of security so not anyone with access to your PC can generate build `APKs` if you have checked to save the `KeyStore` password.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh I understand it now. Thank you for you help :)